# Unity 2018.3: How can I apply a texture on just one part of a whole 3D Model?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, fbx

I have a question about 3D models in Unity (Unity 2018.3). How can I apply a texture to just one part of a whole 3D model? Because I downloaded some 3D Models from the Internet (with no Copyright and I am allowed to use them) and some of them have every part textured separately. And not just one Texture for the whole model.

Or how could I merge these textures with the model (or the parts of the Model) before importing in Unity? And when I import this, it should be textured.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You should Import the model into Blender.
Go into Edit Mode and select the faces of the parts you want to separate and Press P key , select "Selected" option and this will the split the model into two, now you can create textures for the separated parts.
2. After importing into blender , Go into Edit Mode and select the faces of the parts you want and find the "Material" icon and select New Material. Now you have two meshes.

Once you are done you can save the complete model and import into unity.
Ref:
https://wiki.nexusmods.com/index.php/Splitting_meshes_in_Blender 
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200919164914/https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=574)

Comment: Will this also work for .fbx, .obj or .dae files in blender? Because sometimes when I import these files into blender they are a little bit weird. And importing .dae files into blender isn't working for me. When I import it, nothing happens...